# having problems installing ruby gem "bluepill" on ubuntu

Tags: ruby, rubygems

1. i install bluepill on ubuntu:
   Linux auto 2.6.31-14-server #48-Ubuntu SMP Fri Oct 16 15:07:34 UTC 2009 x86_64 GNU/Linux

```
Actual Result:
root@auto:/# gem install bluepill
Successfully installed bluepill-0.0.43
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for bluepill-0.0.43...
Installing RDoc documentation for bluepill-0.0.43...
root@auto:/# bluepill
bluepill: command not found
root@auto:/#
```

1. I install bluepill on ubuntu:
   Linux autobot 2.6.27-7-server #1 SMP Tue Nov 4 20:18:35 UTC 2008 i686 GNU/Linux

`stdout:`

gem install bluepill
Successfully installed blankslate-2.1.2.3
Successfully installed state_machine-0.9.4
Successfully installed bluepill-0.0.43
3 gems installed
Installing ri documentation for blankslate-2.1.2.3...
Installing ri documentation for state_machine-0.9.4...
Installing ri documentation for bluepill-0.0.43...
Installing RDoc documentation for blankslate-2.1.2.3...
Installing RDoc documentation for state_machine-0.9.4...
Installing RDoc documentation for bluepill-0.0.43...

Actual output:

`root@autobot:~# bluepill
Usage: bluepill [app] cmd [options]
    -l, --logfile LOGFILE            Path to logfile, defaults to /var/log/bluepill.log
    -c, --base-dir DIR               Directory to store bluepill socket and pid files, defaults to /var/bluepill
    -v, --version
        --[no-]privileged            Allow/disallow to run /usr/bin/bluepill as non-privileged process. disallowed by default
    -h, --help                       Show this message`

Commands:
    load CONFIG_FILE        Loads new instance of bluepill using the specified config file
    status          Lists the status of the proceses for the specified app
    start [TARGET]      Issues the start command for the target process or group, defaults to all processes
    stop [TARGET]       Issues the stop command for the target process or group, defaults to all processes
    restart [TARGET]        Issues the restart command for the target process or group, defaults to all processes
    unmonitor [TARGET]      Stop monitoring target process or group, defaults to all processes
    log [TARGET]        Show the log for the specified process or group, defaults to all for app
    quit            Stop bluepill

See http://github.com/arya/bluepill for README

Comment: While I don't have an answer for you, I _do_ think this belongs on StackOverflow.